# Do SagePay have a list of IP ranges that their simulator responses can be server from?

Tags: opayo

I have a test/staging site set up, but access to that site is restricted by IP address.

This means that, although I can post to the SagePay simulator fine, the return response is denied by the web server.

Is there a published list of IP addresses/ranges that the SagePay simulator servers use so that I can whitelist them?

Cheers,

Mike

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about deployment policies of a third party system.

Comment: this is a valid programming question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sage Pay own the entire 195.170.169.0/255 range so if you whitelist all these I.P. addresses you will cover our full list, whether using Test, Simulator or Live.

Comment: The IP range in CIDR format is 195.170.169.0/24 (which is 195.170.169.0-255)

Comment: If you have the option of whitelisting the AS number instead of an IP range, that is likely to be more robust as any changes to IP ranges used by SagePay may be more likely to be done via their owned AS39849.  As an example, in the Cloudflare Firewall you can create a rule to "bypass" all security features for AS 39849 (if you just "allow", then the requests could still be blocked by the WAF).