# Does SagePay have a list of IP ranges to whitelist in VPN?

Tags: ip, opayo, whitelist

I use a test store with VPN access. I need to test working with SagePay. I would like to whitelist their IPs so that there is connection.

I read the question [Do SagePay have a list of IP ranges that their simulator responses can be server from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620191/do-sagepay-have-a-list-of-ip-ranges-that-their-simulator-responses-can-be-server)
but this issue is over 4 years old.
I asked SagePay support  2 days ago, but I haven’t received an answer yet.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

For TEST:
    IP 195.170.169.59 https://pi-test.sagepay.com 
    IP 195.170.169.8   https://test.sagepay.com

Sage Pay must white list your IP on its side.